# How to remove the close (×) button from Eclipse Juno tabs?

Tags: eclipse, css

Is it possible to remove the close button from main editor tabs? I've heard there is a new UI model in Eclipse Juno (e4) that uses CSS for tuning, so is it possible to write some CSS to remove close button from the tabs?

I didn't found anything useful regarding available css rules and selector for the new UI.

Answer (score 5):

Just found a solution:

1. First you need to install E4 tools (from update site http://download.eclipse.org/e4/updates/0.12/): *Er CSS Editor (Incubation)* and restart Eclipse
2. Now go to Preferences (menu *Window* → *Preferences*, then *Appearance*), there you should find CSS editor for Eclipse UI
3. Add the following piece of code at the end of CSS code:

   ```
   CTabItem {
       swt-show-close: false !important;   
   }
   ```
4. Restart eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sergey,

You don't have to install any plugin to actually edit the CSS file. If you goto

> (eclipse-folder)/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.***/css/e4_default_gtk.css

and edit this file you will get the same result.

```
CTabItem {
    swt-show-close: false !important;   
}
```

Comment: Just an update for _Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)_ - The path is a bit different; `eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.300.v20181108-1102/css/e4_default_gtk.css` and `css/dark/e4-dark_globalstyle.css` for the dark theme.