# How to decrease the width of splitter in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, css, user-interface

I am a bit annoyed with a width of splitter that separates views. In my opinion it is too wide. I haven't found any option in preferences to change this.

[image]

Perhaps can be solved by tricking CSS [like here](https://superuser.com/questions/444763). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One should simply switch the theme to "Classic":

`Preferences → General → Appearance → Theme = Classic`